# How to pass parameters between two uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, parameters

I have to send parameters between two UIView. This is how I'm loading the second UIView from the first:

```
SingleViewController *single = [[SingleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SingleViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:single.view];
```

How can i send some NSString to the other view?

Comment: What do you mean by "The other view"?  Do you mean self.view or single.view?

Comment: Why don't you pass the parameter to the second controller? If it is responsible for that view, it should do the modification itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then I think you would send the NSString to the view controller (single) and not the view (single.view).
Two common ways to do this come to mind.  Set up a property for SingleViewController class in it's .h file using @property, and then either:
1. set the property like

```
single.somestring = @"this is a string";
```

or 2.  Create a new init method for SingleViewController and pass it in that way.

```
   SingleViewController *single = [[SingleViewController alloc] initWithMyString:@"this is a string" withNibName:@"SingleViewController" bundle:nil];
```

where you have declared `initWithMyString:withNibName:bundle`: in your `SingleViewController.h` file and in it you call `initWithNibName:bundle`: for the parent class.